# Modifying windows registry key

Tags: windows, activex, hta

Does anyone ever used an `OLE` or an `ActiveX` to modify the windows registry keys?

I have found some documentation to do it in command line, but I would like a way to program it otherwise.

Our context is an HTA application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For COM objects to access the Registry from scripts or classic ASP you can choose from :

The "Set" methods of the WMI StdRegProv class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

or

The WshShell RegWrite method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfdfhz1b%28v=vs.85%29.aspx